# Как сделать кодировку JSON в UTF8 до сериализации swift

Tags: ios, json, xcode, utf-8, кодировка

Как сделать кодировку JSON в UTF8 до сериализации?

```
func parseJSONData(data: NSData) -> [News] {

    do {
        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
        let jsonNews = jsonResult["posts"] as! [AnyObject]
        for jsonnewes in jsonNews {
            let newsJson = News()
            newsJson.newsTitle = jsonnewes["post_title"] as! String
            newsJson.newsAutor = jsonnewes["author_name"] as! String
            newsJson.newsFullText = jsonnewes["full_text"] as! String
            newsJson.newsImage = jsonnewes["image"] as! String



            newsItems.append(newsJson)
            print("\(jsonnewes[0])")

        }

    } catch {
        print(error)

}

return newsItems
}
```

Comment: а зачем вам такое?

Comment: потому что данные приходят на казахском языке

Answer (score 1):

я думаю если перевести в стринг и обратно в дату должно получиться

```
NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // или в чем там у вас хранится
data = [temp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Swift

```
let temp:String = String(data: data as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
data = temp.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
```

Comment: Как на swift будет?

Comment: так вы хоть бы тэг свифт поставили. сейчас напишу

Comment: Ругается нету говорит такого параметра как Encoding

Comment: у вас третий свифт или 2.2?

Comment: У меня xcode 7.3.1

Comment: тогда вместо `String.Encoding.utf8` делайте `NSUTF8StringEncoding`

Comment: Ко мне пришел JSON как NSData, я его переделываю в NSString и делаю кодировку в UFT8, теперь мне надо NSString дать или переделать обратно в NSData но не могу сообразить как.  
Вот такой код написал но prin выдает опять не в нужном варианте
`let temp: NSString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            let myNSData = temp.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            print("This is ENCODING DATA: \(myNSData)")
            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(myNSData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary`